# How to control flash movie using activex wrapper?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How to play the flash movie always from the beginning ?
Any way to rewind movie ?

I have use rewind() method for that but it didn't work.

Any help is welcomed....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
At first I have tried Rewind() method of activeX wrapper but it didn't work.

Another good approach is to Call Flash function from VC++.

m_Flash.CallFunction("<invoke name=\"MethodName\"returntype=\"xml\"><arguments></arguments></invoke>");
```